# Adding space in a character array C#

Tags: c#

So basically I have an input string and I have to return a string after adding space after every character in the string.

Eg. input = `abcd` output=`a b c d`

I wrote this piece of code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input1 = "abcd";
        char[] output = new char[999];
        int j = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < input1.Length; i++)
        {
            output[j] = input1[i];
            j = j + 1;
            output[j] =' ';
        }
    
        Console.Write(output[1]); //Why does this print b? I have inserted a blank space at index 1, right?
    
        for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(output[i]);
    
        string op = new string(output);
        return op;
    }
}
```

So that's my question, how does it get `b` at index `1` when I have inserted a blank space.
I am not sure if there are any other shortcuts to do this task. I am completely new to C#. Thanks for all the help. :)

**EDIT:** This is my first time posting here, sorry for the messed up formatting of the text and code.

Answer (score 4):

wouldn't simpler if you use to char array, you get the same results

```
var input = "abcd";
var output = string.Join(" ", input.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: This is the best way to do this.  @Avishek Paul If you want to know why your code didn't work it is because you're resetting the "space" at the beginning of the next loop.  If you step through your debugger you will probably see your output is only one element longer than your input.  If you want YOUR code to work then you'll need to increment "j" once more at the end of each loop.

Comment: Thank you @dogyear for the explanation. I should have been more careful. :)